# Visualforce PageReference - Name Constructor vs. Factory

Tags: apex, visualforce, bestpractice, performance

For a developer who wants to use a `PageReference` to redirect to a `Visualforce Page`, are there any notable differences between constructing it by name versus using the `Page.PageName` factory method?

**By Name**

```
PageReference p1 = new PageReference('/apex/MyPage');
```

**Factory**

```
PageReference p2 = Page.MyPage
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Today I Learned. From the Spring '17 Release Notes on [Allow CSRF Protection on GET Requests to Visualforce Pages (Critical Update)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_vf_crsf_protection_cruc.htm?edition=&impact=):

> CRSF [sic] checks on GET requests also affect how Visualforce pages are referenced from Apex controllers. Methods that return the URL of CRSF-protected [sic] pages for navigation don’t work:
>
> ```
> public String getPage() {
>     return '/apex/PageName'; 
> }
> ```
>
> Instead, use methods that return a reference to the Visualforce page instead of the URL directly.
>
> ```
> public class customController {
>     public PageReference getPage() {
>         return new PageReference('/apex/PageName'); 
>     }
>     public PageReference getPage1() {
>         return Page.PageName; 
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: +1 ... I need to learn to read release notes. Also, I have about 50 pages to fix in our org...

Comment: Ouch. I know the pain of pervious developers leaving a mess behind them. Hopefully others don't say that about *my* code...

Comment: It also says for the pages with `CSRF protection enabled`, we cannot simply access the page by typing url in the browser. Out of curiosity, I tried this in my Spring'17 and get this error when accessing the page  **The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator. **

Comment: Yeah I found that interesting as well. Seems a bit odd.

Comment: I was about to edit the "CRSF" acronym, but that is how they spell it in the documentation.

Comment: @martin good catch. I wonder if there is any sort of feedback mechanism...

Answer (score 12):

One important aspect, besides the CRSF limitation, is that when you use the string constructor, you're explicitly avoiding creating a metadata link between your page and the class.

What this means for you is that if someone decides that your page is no longer used, and they delete the page, it can break your code, as you'll now be redirecting to a non-existent page. If you use the factory variable instead, you get automatic metadata protection. Similarly, if you make a typo in a string, you won't be notified, while if you're using the Page factory, you'll avoid simple typos or missing files during deployment.

When you attempt to delete the page, you'll be notified that the page is used in that class. Also, you can see a page's usage by clicking on the "Where is this used" button in the UI. This only detects "strong" links to the page, not weak links, such as using plain URLs. Change sets and packages also provide dependency management, but they can't protect you from simple string references.

Similarly, when possible, you should prefer to use the $Page global variable to link pages together, and use the Visualforce URL type for custom buttons and links that reference the page. Creating strong links in your metadata will help prevent accidental deletions.

Comment: +1 Yeah I thought about posting this as a separate answer. It's not really a pro or con, per se. True, I tend to prefer strong metadata links, but sometimes you don't want to tightly couple components. At least, in some circumstances you might create a circular reference using the factory pattern.

Comment: @AdrianLarson From personal experience, I can say it's a pro. I've never had a situation arise where using the string somehow saved me effort, but I can tell you that I can't count the number of times I've deleted a page because "Where is this used?" showed no results...

Comment: If you had a multi-step wizard with back and forward buttons, for instance, wouldn't it be a royal PITA to delete them? For the record, I always use the factory pattern and consider it best practice. I'm not trying to advocate for string constructors.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Nope. If you delete a page with its class at the same time, you won't trigger the protection mechanism. So, I'd build a simple destructiveChanges.xml with all of the wizard classes and pages, and workbench deploy. Problem solved. On the other hand, our org has 161 pages, which we're cleaning up for Lightning. Unfortunately, prior developers have not used Page references, so I can no longer easily identify which pages I can delete without manually searching all of our metadata...