# How to handle deep links without CSRF tokens gracefully?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, bestpractice, deep-linking, csrf

CSRF protection is mandatory now, and we have enabled it on our public site successfully, but as [this previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166711/the-link-you-followed-isn-t-valid-this-page-requires-a-csrf-confirmation-token/166735#166735) notes, plain links (such as emailed URLs or bookmarks) to protected pages don't work. Instead they end up at our code 500 server-side error page, which is not the right message for the situation.

Is there a way to handle these links and get authenticated users to the right pages?

If not, what is the right way to handle these external links?