# Suddenly need to update buttons to use URLFOR

Tags: critical-update, release-update

Suddenly it looks like i need to update custom buttons that have worked for eons to use URLFOR

old: `/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess?masterId={!fHCM2__Employment__c.Id}&templateId=a1m1W000004SFLE`

new:

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/echosign_dev1__AgreementTemplateProcess','null',[masterId=fHCM2__Employment__c.Id,templateId='a1m1W000004SFLE'])}
```

else I get the error

> The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF
> confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce
> administrator.

I did not see this coming at all - what did I miss?  I did just update Adobe Sign yesterday, which seems like the most likely cause.   The adobe sign docs do now say to use URLFOR, but previously they did not.  Appreciate any insight to help me understand how I missed this.  Now back to work updating a dozen buttons...

Comment: see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166735/2602)

Comment: thanks unfortunately the H&T articles that show up in google searches are rendering in Korean again, and cant be found to boot, but from the google snippets it looks like this setting may be applied at the page level itself which explains how the update caused this issue, and how i skated by for so long.

Comment: confirmed - the page did not have it checked previously.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're meant to use `$Page.pageName` instead of `/apex/pageName`:

```
{!URLFOR(
    $Page.echosign_dev1.AgreementTemplateProcess, 
    null, 
    [
      masterId=fHCM2__Employment__c.Id, 
      templateId='a1m1W000004SFLE'
    ]
  )
}
```

I'm not entirely sure of the exact syntax to use for a managed package page, but this should get you most of the way there. It's advised that you use CSRF tokens if possible to prevent unintended access to that resource.